# Extract string html with regex on interval

Tags: javascript, html, regex

There is a public website with this in the source:

```
</div><script type="text/rocketscript">
function calculateIndexIncome() {
    var khs = $('#t9').val();
    var btcusd = $('#t9_1').val();
    var btckhs = $('#t9_2').val();
    var dayprofitperkhs = 0.00000018188885404454654
    var arr = btcusd.split(' ');
    btcusd = arr[0];

    var totalinvestmentusd = ((khs * btckhs) * btcusd).toFixed(2);
    var totalinvestmentbtc = (khs * btckhs).toFixed(8);
    var dailyincomebtc = (khs * dayprofitperkhs).toFixed(8);
    var dailyincomeusd = ((khs * dayprofitperkhs) * btcusd).toFixed(2);
    var monthlyincomebtc = (dailyincomebtc * 31).toFixed(8);
    var monthlyincomeusd = (dailyincomeusd * 31).toFixed(2);
    var breakevendays = (totalinvestmentusd / dailyincomeusd).toFixed(0);
    var monthlypercentage = ((100 / breakevendays) * 30).toFixed(2);

    $('#tl').html('Total KHS: ' + khs + '<br/>Total Investment: ' + totalinvestmentbtc + ' BTC ($' + totalinvestmentusd + ' USD)<br/><br/>Daily Income: ' + dailyincomebtc + ' BTC ($' + dailyincomeusd + ' USD)<br/>Monthly Income: ' + monthlyincomebtc + ' BTC ($' + monthlyincomeusd + ' USD)<br/><br/>Break Even In: ' + breakevendays + ' Days.<br/><br/>Monthly Rate: ' + monthlypercentage + '%');
}
```

I need to be able to extract two values: btckhs and dayprofitperkhs.
if I look at page source, dayprofitperkhs is different everytime I refresh.

Edit:

Jimmy Chandra came up with this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:
setInterval(logging,60000);
w1 = window.open("https://scrypt.cc/index.php");
function logging(){
console.log (w1.$('#t9_2').val());
var re=/var\s*dayprofitperkhs\s*=\s*([0-9\.]+)\s*/gi;
var matches=re.exec(document.body.innerHTML);
console.log(RegExp.$1);
w1.location.href = 'https://scrypt.cc/index.php';
}
```

This works ALMOST perfectly. it gets the dayprofitperkhs, but only on the first interval.
After that, the value is no longer updated, although t9_2 IS updated...

Anyone?

Comment: go grab the window document body, use regex to extract it... `/var dayprofitperkhs = ([0-9\.])+\s*$/` maybe and get the match.

Comment: I have no idea how, but if you mean I could just extract that string from the source code, that would be great! Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where that site is, so I am just running this against this SO question, but the following bookmarklet is getting me what I want...

As I mentioned in the comment, I use Regular Expression against the document body inner html and I am looking for `dayprofitperkhs` and capturing the numbers and decimal separator on the right side of the equal sign.  Also trying to compensate for any extra spaces in between (`\s*`).  `RegExp.$1` gave me the number that I am looking for.

```
javascript:(function(){var re=/var\s*dayprofitperkhs\s*=\s*([0-9\.]+)\s*/gi;var matches=re.exec(document.body.innerHTML);console.log(RegExp.$1);}());
```

So your final bookmarklet should be something like:

```
javascript:
setInterval(logging,60000);
w1 = window.open("siteurl.com");
function logging(){
console.log (w1.$('#t9_2').val());
var re=/var\s*dayprofitperkhs\s*=\s*([0-9\.]+)\s*/gi;
var matches=re.exec(w1.document.body.innerHTML);
console.log(RegExp.$1);
w1.location.href = 'siteurl.com';
}
```

Comment: Screamed victory too soon... It only fetches the value the first time, after that value stays the same. I had it log for 8 hours as a test with an interval of 5 minutes. Value of t9_2 was different everytime, but dayprofitperkhs remained the same.

Comment: Is it not a constant? can't tell from the code snippet that you posted.  If some backend code is injecting that every page refresh, I'd think it will be changing unless they are doing some other things that not displayed above...

Comment: fixed it: , needed to add w1 to document.body.innerHTML

Comment: Of  course :)  You need to operate on the w1 windows. I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The variables in question are local variables within the `calculateIndexIncome()` function, so no, you can't access them from outside that function.

The reason the first one "works" is because you're not referring to the variable, but rather the value: `$('#t9_2').val()`. This is a jquery selector which finds the element with the ID `t9_2` and grabs its value.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot visit it because its a local variable, it only exists in calculateIndexIncome() function.

By the way, you needn't open a new window to visit the variables. You can use chrome dev tools to directly modify the javascript to print the values, or set a breakpoint to debug the code.

Here is a tutorial for chrome dev tools: https://www.codeschool.com/courses/discover-devtools